# Can I use draft variable in front matter?

Tags: jekyll

Can I make a post in my [site](https://demo.justinechacko.in)to draft using draft variable in front matter of posts like

```
---
.....
draft: true
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways :

1. with a post's front matter variable `published: false` ([documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#predefined-global-variables))
2. by putting your draft posts in a **_drafts** folder ([documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#drafts))